# Cache a large amount of data with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I have a **lot** of data that I can potentially work with, it hardly ever changes, and it's not a problem at all to refresh the cache every now and then - but ideally the cache would be refreshed only when new data enters the table.

I have built with the understanding that CakePHP can cache an entire table and work off of that, even with slower caching like the File cache. Meaning I query once for all information, and if I ever say "findById(54)", it just searches that cache for ID 54 and deals it out. I do not want to only cache the content of ID 54. I also want to avoiding changing the code I have already done. I know that it must be possible to just findAll() and cache that once, but I haven't built with that in mind and I'd rather not go through it all if I don't have to.

My question is, how do I get CakePHP to cache the entire table and query off that cache? Is it possible? I'm open to using memcached, but I'm thinking for its beginning that I would only use File caching.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a **lot** of data

How much is "a lot"?

### Override the find method in your AppModel

A simple technique to do what you want is to hijack find calls in your app model, and return a cached result if there is one, similar to this:

```
public function find($type = 'first', $params = array()) {
    $key = md5(serialize(func_get_args());
    $return = Cache::read($key);
    if (false !== $return) {
        return $cacheResult;
    }

    $return = parent::find($type, $params);
    Cache::write($key, $return);
    return $return;
}
```

In this way, you populate the cache as you use the db, and have the benefit of being able to disable the cache, or have an empty cache, and still have your site work.

Comment: shouldnt you check on false here instead of null? `if ($return !== false) { return $cacheResult; }`

Comment: This looks good, and like it will save me the work of changing the current code. (and all ongoing code muddying) However, I'm not sure it will do as I expect, which is to have all of the data cached and then query from that. In this case, I have large paragraphs of texts that I don't want to be storing in single queries.

Comment: @mark yup. Vael, no it won't do that - because cache doesn't work that way. If you _do_ want to work that way you could choose an appropriate [datasource](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/master/models/datasources), write one, or simply use a nosql store such as couchdb, mongodb etc. Though *how much is "a lot"* because, for example, you can't use memcache and store in memory more data than you have memory. However: what problem are you _actually_ trying to solve? Caching your data is a solution to something and the something is what you should ask about, probably.

Comment: I feared that. The issue is caching the content of a story-heavy game in which there can be many stored words per game. We enter these via a backend, into MySQL. While one game may not use up all of the memory available to memcached, I want to keep as many games on one server as possible. Disk space is cheaper than RAM and so I expect(ed) to use the file system cache.